# Tagged structures casting rules

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, c++20

I was playing around with toy tuple implementations and eventually stuck with how `get` function works.

Consider this simple example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <size_t Tag, typename ValueType>
struct TagedValue { ValueType value; };

struct Test : TagedValue<0, int>, TagedValue<1, std::string>, TagedValue<2, double> {};

template <size_t Idx, typename T>
auto& get(Test& test) {
    ((TagedValue<Idx, T>&)(test)).value;
}

template <size_t Idx, typename T>
auto& get_impl(TagedValue<Idx, T>& tagged_value) {
    return tagged_value.value;
}

template <size_t Idx>
auto& get_2(Test& test) {
    return get_impl<Idx>(test);
}


int main()
{
    Test test;
    get_2<0>(test);
    get<0>(test);
}
```

[I get this error](https://godbolt.org/z/xPWs9hKc8):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:29:16: error: no matching function for call to 'get<0>(Test&)'
   29 |     get<0>(test);
      |                ^
<source>:10:7: note: candidate: 'template<long unsigned int Idx, class T> auto& get(Test&)'
   10 | auto& get(Test& test) {
      |       ^~~
<source>:10:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:29:16: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
   29 |     get<0>(test);
      |                ^
```

I do have couple of questions:

1. Basically why `get_2` works and `get` doesn't compile. To me it looks like `get_2` does exactly what I'm trying to do inside `get`
2. Does deducing T for `get_2` take O(1) time, if yes how is it possible? Does compiler store some kind of map internally?

Comment: please incldue the complete compiler error message in the question. Also it often leads to confusion to post the code that does not produce the error, but requires others to remove some `//` or other modifications. Better post the code that has the error and the complete error message

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You can see the full compiler output here https://godbolt.org/z/hfE68qdvY

Comment: Please try to make your questions self-contained. External links might disappear or get corrupted or get their contents changed.

Comment: and please one question per question. (actually I dont understand the second)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
The second question is basically what is time complexity for compiler to deduce T? Does it depend on number Test's of base calsses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function template then all template arguments must either be specified explicitly or be deduced from the function arguments. When you call

```
get<0>(test);
```

Then `Idx` is `0`, but there is no way for the compiler to know what `T` is supposed to be. The parameter is just `Test`, and `T` cannot be deduced from that.

Comment: Well, the question is how can it deduce it in get_impl?

Comment: @Dmitry well, the question you did ask is "why `get_2` works and `get` doesn't compile."

Comment: It's obvious "why" (I mean what the compiler error is) it fails to compile. The point is there is no any "hints" for compiler inside `get_2`, yet it somehow able to cast `test`(which is of type `Test`) to `tagged_value` (which is in that case of type `TaggedValue<0, int>` by knowing only `Tag` value. I'm doing essentially exactly the same thing inside `get` still it's unbale to deduce `T` there.

Comment: @Dmitry no you are not doing essentially the same thing. `get` need 2 arguments and it is not possible to deduce `T`. WIth `get_2` there is `Idx == 0`. Then `get_impl` again `idx == 0` and `T` can be decuded from the function argument which is `TagedValue<Idx, T>&`. And I admit this is something I dont understand fully in detail.

Comment: @Dmitry I beleive it is covered here ["If P is a class and P has the form simple-template-id, then the transformed A can be a derived class of the deduced A. Likewise, if P is a pointer to a class of the form simple-template-id, the transformed A can be a pointer to a derived class pointed to by the deduced A: ..."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), but I would need to read more to explain in my own words

Comment: @Dmitry and consider this as a slightly simpler example https://godbolt.org/z/fc1jfo5zf (as I tried to explain the wrapper is a red herring, when the function template has two parameters and you supply only one and the other cannot be deduced you already said that it is obvious why its an error)

Comment: Yeap, thanks a lot. I believe `template-id` is the answer here. And I got that my cast in `get` simply does not participate in type deduction.