# How to define equivalent rule for non type template arg

Tags: c++, c++20

After some time of figuring out [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74303189/tagged-structures-casting-rules) I have found it's really fascinating how compiler can deduce template arguments from set of "tags" (non-type template args). But it looks like the compiler only understands "byte by byte" equality rule.

What I mean is this code:

```
struct S1 {
    constexpr S1(int v) : _v(v)
    {};
    constexpr bool operator == (const S1& other) { return true;} 
    int _v;
};

template <S1 Tag, typename ValueType>
struct TagedValue { ValueType value; };

struct Test : TagedValue<S1{0}, int>, TagedValue<S1{1}, double> {};

template <S1 Idx, typename T>
auto& get(TagedValue<Idx, T>& test) {
    return test.value;
}

int main()
{
    Test test;
    get<S1{1}>(test); // Still compiles, even though S1{0} == S1{1}
    static_assert(S1{0} == S1{1});
}
```

As you can see I have defined my own `operator ==` which basically says: "any two instances are equal". But it looks like in order to deduce `T` in `get` function the compiler still checks whether or not the actual content of the struct is the same. That is, for the purpose of type deduction `S1{0} != S2{1}`, even though `S1{0} == S2{1}` from "C++ point of view".

My question is: Is there any way I can redefine that "type deduction equality rule"?

UPD: To make it probably more clear, if I replace this line

```
    struct Test : TagedValue<S1{0}, int>, TagedValue<S1{1}, double> {};
```

with

```
    struct Test : TagedValue<S1{1}, int>, TagedValue<S1{1}, double> {};
```

the compiler gives an error, complaining about ambiguty.

Comment: `S1{0} == S2{1}` compares *values*, not *types*

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, but `S1{0}` is not a type, that's because it's called "non-type template arg" I suppose.

Comment: yes, which base you expect it to pass then?

Comment: @appleapple Could you please explain what you mean? I would expect this code fails to compile because `S1{0}` and `S1{1}` are equal(as defined by `operator ==`) "tags".

Comment: oh I see, you're saying the example should not compile. I originally think you ask why there is ambiguty in updated example.

Comment: https://ctrpeach.io/posts/cpp20-class-as-non-type-template-param/

Comment: `S1{0}` and `S1{1}` may compare equal but are not *the same*. There is no way to force them to be the same. If you have `char c = 1` and `int i = 1`, then `c == i`, but I think it's clear that `c` and `i` are not the same.

Comment: @Nelfeal It's not **that** clear actually. In your example int and char are two different types, so they are not the same for sure. As I can see the equality here has something with static duration. Basically two objects are the same if and only if they exist in the same "static constexpr memory".

Comment: @Dmitry "so they are not the same for sure" - that's the point. The fact that two objects compare equal does not mean they are the same, contrary to what you seemed to expect. Also, it has nothing to do with memory location: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sY5159aEf).

Comment: @Nelfeal yes, as IgorTandetnik answered it is recursive member-wise equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template parameter deduction, and other template-related things, use the concept of [type equivalence](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type). The parts relevant to your question are these:

> [**temp.type/1**](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type#1) Two *template-ids* are the same if
> ...
> (1.3) - their corresponding non-type *template-arguments* are template-argument-equivalent (see below) after conversion to the type of the *template-parameter*...
>
> [**temp.type/2**](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.type#2) Two values are *template-argument-equivalent* if they are of the same type and
> ...
> (2.10) - they are of class type and their corresponding direct subobjects and reference members are template-argument-equivalent.

Roughly, it's member-wise equality. No, you cannot override it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not override the equality check for template parameter objects:

> An identifier that names a non-type template parameter of class type T denotes a static storage duration object of type const T, called a template parameter object, whose value is that of the corresponding template argument after it has been converted to the type of the template parameter. **All such template parameters in the program of the same type with the same value denote the same template parameter object.** A template parameter object shall have constant destruction.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters